# Форум Discuss для Modx

Tags: modx, forum

Как устанавливать и настраивать нашел. А где можно посмотреть пример, как в итоге он выглядит?

Comment: discuss уже вечность не обновлялся (лет 6). И в целом проект мёртв. Используйте [Tickets](https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/tickets). Информации море по нему. Хотя, если прям форум в классическом понимании, то можно и [SMF](https://modstore.pro/packages/other/smf)

Comment: Спасибо, установил SMF, всё нравится. Как закрыть вопрос?